# What is the measure of the largest base ($AB$) of the trapeze $ABCD$ below?

Tags: geometry

For reference: The smaller base of an ABCD trapezoid measures 5. Parallels are drawn along A and B
to non-parallel sides. Calculate the measure of the largest base knowing that these parallels
intersect at a point on the median of the trapezius.

My progress:

[image]

For parallels to meet at the median, the trapeze needs to be isosceles

$\triangle AEH ~is~isosceles$

If we can demonstrate that FD is base and average of GK the problem would be over

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information. AB could be any length and you could still have isosceles trapezoid ABCD.

Comment: @Andria...You're right... we can have numerous isosceles trapezoids with parallels intersecting at the median. Some data was missing to narrow the problem. The answer in the book is 15.